# How do I differentiate $f^3(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus

I am learning about the chain rule and I'm not sure about kind of having to do it twice?

So say I have the function $f^{3}(g(x))$, how would I differentiate this to find $f'(x)$ using the chain rule?

Ok so what I have tried to do is say:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f^3(g(x)) = 3f^2(g(x))f'(g(x))g'(x).$$

However, something tells me this is incorrect.

Comment: Is $f^3(x^2)=f(f(f(x^2)))$?

Comment: When you say $f^3$, do you mean $f(f(f(x^2)))$, or $\left(f(x^2)\right)^3$?

Comment: A lot of students are doing tests at the moment so you are going to have to show some work before you even get a hint. Then again, seems to be people happy to do that for you....

Comment: @unknown: "something tells me this is incorrect" what makes you think that? Can you elaborate what are the parts where you feel unsure about?

Comment: When I help in closing a question, I also follow up and ensure that once updates have come and the question is fit for reopening, we do so. This question is undergoing that process, and all answerers can *freely* use the comments to communicate with the author and help them bring their post to the desired quality. It is not necessary that an *attempt* needs to do this , the mention of : "what I'm studying right, where I'm studying it from and have I done similar problems before" is also sufficient.

Comment: @unknown Coming to this question, if $f^{3}(g(x)) = \big(f(g(x))\big)^3$, which I think you use, then you are in fact correct.

Answer (score -3):

**HINT**

Let's differentiate $f^2(x^2) = f(f(x^2))$. You get

$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(f(x^2))
 = f'(f(x^2)) \frac{d}{dx} f(x^2)
 = f'(f(x^2))f'(x^2)\frac{d}{dx} x^2
 = f'(f(x^2))f'(x^2) \cdot 2x
$$

Another possible interpretation is that you mean $f^2(x^2) = (f(x^2))^2$ (but this is unlikely since we usually write that as $f(x^2)^2$, not as $f^2(x^2)$. If this is what you mean though, you would get
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (f(x^2))^2
 = 2f(x^2)\frac{d}{dx}f(x^2)
 = 2f(x^2) f'(x^2) \frac{d}{dx} x^2
 = 4x f(x^2) f'(x^2)
$$

Comment: Please do not answer low-quality questions, see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: @supinf as you can see, I did not do the problem for the OP but got him started with a hint, asking for more contributions. It is a different way to make him do some work. on the problem, improving the quality of the question.

Comment: @gt6989b And the established way to do that is to ask for that in comments, not post a substantial answer post. See [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards): "don't answer it immediately.  Instead, direct the user to the meta post [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Help them to understand what the standards are on this site, and consider offering advice on how they might improve their question."

Comment: @Arthur the user actually updated his question with what seems to be the correct approach according to at least one interpretation of the problem...

Comment: @gt6989b Great spot! It's already been informed in CURED, and we'll get the question back up, it's now at three reopen votes : pardon me, I just changed it to four.

Comment: @gt6989b It is appropriate to put hints in the comments below the question.  Please do not answer such questions until the original asker can address the issues of clarity and context pointed out in the comments.